# Turning cellphone to landscape- how to start at onStart()?

Tags: android, landscape-portrait

Goal:
When I turn the cellphone from portrait to landscape I would like to begin from scratch that you start at onStart().

Problem:
What part am I missing in order to make it?

Thank you!

Info:
*I'm new in android
*I'm using API 23

---

### [image]

MainActivity

```
package com.jfdimarzio.myapplication2;


import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.location.LocationProvider;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.format.Time;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private TextView texten = null;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        texten = new TextView(this);
        texten.setText("");
        setContentView(texten);
        Log.d("StateInfo", "onCreate");
        print("onCreate");
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();
        Log.d("StateInfo", "onStart");
        print("onStart");
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d("StateInfo", "onResume");
        print("onResume");
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        Log.d("StateInfo", "onPause");
        print("onPause");
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStop()
    {
        super.onStop();
        Log.d("StateInfo", "onStop");
        print("onStop");
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d("StateInfo", "onDestroy");
        print("onDestroy");
    }


    private void print(String text) {
        Time now = new Time();
        now.setToNow();
        String timeString = now.format("%H:%M:%S");
        String line = timeString + ": " + text + "\n";
        texten.setText(texten.getText() + line);
        texten.invalidate();
        texten.postInvalidate();
    }


}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.jfdimarzio.myapplication2">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.jfdimarzio.myapplication2.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Delete this line from your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
```

This line declares that *you* will handle these "configuration changes", rather than allowing the system to automatically destroy and recreate your activities. If you want the default handling, just get rid of this line.

Comment: I have removed it but the same problem is still occuring

Comment: Could you explain the problem? I put your code into my own app and I see what I'd expect to see, so maybe the problem is that your expectation doesn't match mine.

Comment: You run the emulator, you see the app in portrait and you can see some text taht is oncreate etc. Then you make it into landscape, then the message should be writing OnStart and onResume in landscape.
I don't know how to do it.

Comment: When I copy and paste your code into my app (which doesn't have that `configChanges` attribute), here's what I see: (1) I launch the app (2) I see lines for `onCreate()`, `onStart()`, and `onResume()` (3) I rotate the device (4) I see lines for `onCreate()`, `onStart()`, and `onResume()`, but with new timestamps. Which part of this do you not want?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the Activity to start up and stay in landscape, you might as well set the activity to landscape mode:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
          android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: It works however it doesn't start from scrtach in relation to onStart()

Comment: `onStart(...)` is a lifecycle method that exists separately of the orientation. "from scratch" isn't clear. Please describe the order which you think this should be running?

Comment: `onStart(...)` will also ALWAYS come after `onCreate(...)`. It will never happen before `onCreate(...)`. Please review the activity lifecycle in the android documentation as it might help you understand why `onStart(...)` doesn't happen first: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html